# Email Template: Form and input not working on outlook.com

Tags: html, css, email, outlook.com

As we know, Outlook.com is taking over Hotmail. HTML form and input fields in the email template no more working on Outlook.com. The problems which include:

- Form cannot be submit
- Input text field looks weird
- Input radio cannot be select
- etc

What is the best solution to fix this problem in the email template for Outlook.com?

Comment: It's the behavior than with outlook (the software). Please, don't use form in email.

Comment: @Shikiryu The conversion rate works great with the form in the email template, this is the reason we need it. And it works fine on gmail, yahoo mail and others.

Comment: How would you know for the conversion rate? Do you have any sources? FORMs aren't suited for email and many spam blockers consider forms in email as spam (which I find very appropriate). I would advise you to "fake" a form in your email template which would link to a real form on the web.

Comment: @Shikiryu Spam blocker will not block the email because of form in email template. We have been used the form in the mail template for year. If we found that the form cannot be accepted in other mail clients, i won't ask the question only Outlook.com.

Answer (score 5):

`FORM`s cannot be used in emails. You'll find them stripped out on many mail clients.

Comment: No, most of the mail clients can be accept form in email template. We have been used for years now. We can see the conversion rates come from each mail clients. For those people who down vote me, please do some research and try yourself before click the vote button. I don't really care about the vote, but we do care about the answer to solve our problem.

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't the answer you want but I think the best solution to support the most e-mail clients is to have a link to fill out the form outside of the e-mail for the users that can't do it in the e-mail.

In general support for forms in HTML e-mail isn't the greatest and from this chart it looks like Hotmail wasn't supported before so I wouldn't expect that to change in the near future.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, forms aren't universally supported in HTML emails.

- Additional reading: http://www.emailology.org/